# How can you access the original tag or filename text in a mp3 with a MusicBrainz: Picard plugin?

Tags: python, regex, plugins, musicbrainz

I am trying to access the filename or MetaData I have added to my music over the years. (Live), (Demo), (Live: In Athens), (Acoustic), (Live In Las Vegas 2005), (Metallica Cover), (Bonus Track), etc. I've done this to distinguish between tracks easily.

I an going through trying to fix my music and organize/tag it better with MusicBrainz Picard. But Picard doesn't allow access to the original Tags, or Filename. Relying only on what is pulled from their database. (As you can see my info isn't standard. and it's just for me and my own personal collection, so most of it, would be useless to add to their database)

So one of the Forum Admins/Programmers (I think), Suggested that maybe it was possible to do this through a plugin.

I've never programmed in Python, and don't know the first thing about it. lately i've barely been getting into RegEx. But have a Fairly decent, though not advanced understanding of that.

Now, Ideally I'd like to check the original metadata if possible, and then check the filename. and pull out anything in () and save it to a Several Variables in the file as they are there: ExtraInfo1, ExtraInfo2, etc. then check each against the title to make sure it's not already in the title as sometimes the titles themselves have parentheses in their titles. then if not, be able to add them back to the title. to tag and rename them.

I did find this plugin, which pulls information out of the title and moves it to the version tag. So that is almost exactly what i'm looking for, except instead of taking it from the Title tag, i'd like to take it from the original title tag, or the filename. then add it to the new Title tag.

Could someone maybe help me with this?

here's the plugin I found:

```
PLUGIN_NAME = 'Move metadata to version tag'
PLUGIN_AUTHOR = 'Jacob Rask'
PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION = 'Moves song metadata such as "demo", "live" from title and titlesort to version tag.'
PLUGIN_VERSION = "0.1.4"
PLUGIN_API_VERSIONS = ["0.12", "0.15"]
from picard.metadata import register_track_metadata_processor
import re
_p_re = re.compile(r"\(.*?\)")
_v_re = re.compile(r"((\s|-)?(acoustic|akustisk|album|bonus|clean|club|cut|C=64|dance|dirty|disco|encore|extended|inch|maxi|live|original|radio|redux|rehearsal|reprise|reworked|ringtone|[Ss]essions?|short|studio|take|variant|version|vocal)(\s|-)?|.*?(capp?ella)\s?|(\s|-)?(alternat|demo|dub|edit|ext|fail|instr|long|orchestr|record|remaster|remix|strument|[Tt]ape|varv).*?|.*?(complete|mix|inspel).*?)")
def add_title_version(tagger, metadata, release, track):
if metadata["titlesort"]:
title = metadata["titlesort"]
else:
title = metadata["title"]
pmatch = _p_re.findall(title)
if pmatch: # if there's a parenthesis, investigate
pstr = pmatch[-1][1:-1] # get last match and strip paranthesis
vmatch = _v_re.search(pstr)
if vmatch:
metadata["titlesort"] = re.sub("\(" + pstr + "\)", "", title).strip()
metadata["title"] = re.sub("\(" + pstr + "\)", "", title).strip()
metadata["version"] = pstr
register_track_metadata_processor(add_title_version)
```

Thanks,
-Dev

Comment: As far as I can see, this has nothing to do with Java.  Removing tag-spam.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MusicBrainz Picard was programmed in Java.

Comment: But how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: Picard is not written in Java but Python. Accessing the filename in the tagger script or in a plugin that's called in the tagger script is (iirc) not possible, but there's a [ticket](http://tickets.musicbrainz.org/browse/PICARD-259) for it. Accessing custom tags that were not overwritten by Picard should be possible, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: Aww. I thought it just used Python for it's plugins. I haven't been able to get it to read tags that Picard didn't overwrite. But one of the admins/And maybe coder on Picard, said that it should be possible to get that info with a plugin. so I thought that might be next route to try.